# Using formula in format

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use a custom formula in [format] in a google spreadsheet.

I have 2 columns (A and B) with one [year] in A and another [year] in B.

If the difference between A1 and B1 is 1 then the 2 cells should have the color green. If the difference are 2 then the 2 cells should be yellow - and finally if the difference is above 2 then no color.That goes on from A1:B100.

I have tried to use the formula [=IF(B1-A1=1] in the format part and chosen a color, but it wont work. Can anyone help?

I don't want to make an extra row showing the difference between A and B and the format the cell if the number is 1,2 or 3. I want to keep it within the formating of the cells.

Best regards
Jacob

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the IF, an equality check will automatically evaluate to TRUE or FALSE (or an error)

Try using:

```
=ABS($B1 - $A1) = 1
```

And apply the conditional formatting to the range A1:B100

Comment: Thank you very much - it works :) I didn't thought of using absolute variables  as I wanted it to work for the whole area, but that was the way. Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: If this helped you please accept the answer thanks :)